# Playing local video file in a Chrome Packaged App

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to play a local video file from a packaged app? I have already written the code to choose the file(chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry) and identify the path(chrome.fileSystem.getDisplayPath), but setting it to the source of my video tag returns:

Not allowed to load local resource: file:///

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've made some progress but not something good enough.

I've decided to try loading it as a data-uri and set it to the src property of the source tag in my video tag, after I've called the method load on my video object and the video got black on my app but it doesn't respond to any command such as play. The process running this app after executing the line that sets the serialized video to the source as an data-uri increased its memory usage to over 1gb.

I think I'll be pragmatic and just set up some video streaming server.

Comment: Have you looked at the GitHub samples? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/media-gallery might work if you're OK going through the Media Gallery API rather than loading any arbitrary file. It might be adaptable to local files, too.

Comment: I did sowbug, but it's extremely slow to serialize a ~100mb video into a data-uri, almost every time the app crashes. :/

I've tried to copy the video to the persistent area of the app but when I set the src attribute to that address (both the fullpath or toURL of FileEntry) and the request to the video is canceled.

Comment: Will you please file a bug at crbug.com with your crash IDs from chrome://crashes? We would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm going to do that, FYI I'm trying to figure a solution here too: http://bit.ly/19BbP1r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution was to select the local file through this call:

```js
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({'type': 'openFile'}, function(fileEntry) {
    // ...
});
```

With that in memory I got a directory in my sandboxed persistent area:

```js
fileSystem.root.getDirectory('videos', { create : true }, function(dirEntry) {
    // ...
}, $scope.errorHandler);
```

And copied the local file to that directory:

```js
fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry, fileEntry.name, function(newFileEntry) {
    video.src = newFileEntry.toURL();
});
```

That worked perfectly and it's pretty clean, the feature I've not implemented in here but is important is the codec detection, because if you try to load videos that are not supported by Chrome you may think there is something wrong with the code but it's related to the codec/video player.

For further reference here is the complete code:

```js
window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 300*1024*1024, function(fileSystem) {
    console.log('A request to access the file system have been made.');

    $scope.fileSystem = fileSystem;
}, $scope.errorHandler);

$scope.loadVideo = function() {
    chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({'type': 'openFile'}, function(fileEntry) {
       $scope.fileSystem.root.getDirectory('videos', { create : true }, function(dirEntry) {
          fileEntry.copyTo(dirEntry, fileEntry.name, function(newFileEntry) {
            video.src = newFileEntry.toURL();
          });
       }, $scope.errorHandler);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question and ran into the same issues, you cannot load `file:///` urls because of security implications, and using the media gallery example was crashing because my video files are over 150MB.

The chrome team suggested I look at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/apps-resource-loader and use the method the `RAL.RemoteImage` uses to download the file to the sandbox storage and then use it from there.

I use the `ral.min.js` and implemented my own `RemoteVideo` object that I based on the `RemoteImage` object, changing the element to a `video` object instead of an `img` and using the poster instead of a default image before it is loaded and this worked for me.

Comment: dar, thanks for the answer. I was just about answering it too because I've found a similar solution. What I did was to get/create a directory on my app sandbox storage and copy the choosen file there, with the new fileEntry in local memory I called the toURL() method and got the address of the copied video on the persistent storage.

Answer (score 1):

I've found what works is creating an object url from the FileEntry and use is as the `src` for the `<video>` tag. Here's a sample:

```
video_file.file(function(file) {
        var video_url = webkitURL.createObjectURL(file);
        $player.attr("src", video_url);
});
```